# Derandomization barriers in complexity theory applicable as barriers to constructive arguments replacing probabilistic method

Tags: pr.probability, computational-complexity, constructive-mathematics, extremal-combinatorics, probabilistic-method

The probabilistic method as first pioneered by  Erdős  (although others used this before) shows existence of a certain object while finding that object may take exponential time.

**(1)** Is there any known connection between constructive arguments that replace probabilistic methods and derandomization in complexity theory?

**(2)** Do the same barrier that are hurdles to derandomization play a role in limiting progress in constructive mathematics (where constructive mathematics is as within the scope here)?

**(3)** Can every such existence proof in probabilistic methods be derandomized?